# Regular expression for exact one character occurrence at any place of the string

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a Java code that finds a way out from any maze and I need a class that checks generated mazes. Only `.`, `#`, `S`, `X` characters are allowed.

1. `.` and `#` - one and more occurrences at any place of the string are allowed
2. `S` and `X` - one and not more than one occurrence at any place of the string is allowed.

`^[#//.]+$` - regex for the first condition,
But I cannot implement the second one.

The maze input looks like this:

```
.......S..#.
.....###....
..X.........
```

. - empty space, # - wall, S - start, X - exit

Comment: please add some sample input along with desired output

Comment: You can always do it without regular expressions by checking each character in a loop.

Comment: Hint: whenever you have to ask other people "how to write this down as regex" ... that is probably a good indication that *not* using a regex would be the better alternative. You have to interpret that string anyway, so why not write the validation down with simple, distinct code anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [negative lookahead groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), written like `(?!...)`, to accomplish this, like so:

```
^(?!.*S.*S)(?!.*X.*X)[SX.#]+$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/OlnHBS/3)

This accepts any set of characters from your set (`S`, `X`, `.`, `#`) from the start of the string using the `^` and `[SX.#]+`. But it rejects any string containing 2 `S`s (`(?!.*S.*S)`) or 2 `X`s (`(?!.*X.*X)`).

Note that this actually checks both of your conditions. You don't really need 2 regexes here. Based on your example maze, though, it looks like your input can span multiple lines. In that case, you need to add `\n` inside the final character class.

Answer (score 2):

If the maze string consist of all the lines, you could use a single lookahead asserting only a single S, then match only one X (or the other way around)

```
^(?=[^S]*S[^S]*$)[.S#\r\n]*X[.S#\r\n]*$
```

In Java

```
String regex = "^(?=[^S]*S[^S]*$)[.S#\\r\\n]*X[.S#\\r\\n]*$";
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is a single occurrence of `S`

  - `[^S]*S` Match 0+ times any char without `S`, match **S**
  - `[^S]*$` Match 0+ times any char without `S`, end of string
- `)`  Close lookahead
- `[.S#\r\n]*X` Match all accepted chars including a newline without `X`, then match **X**
- `[.S#\r\n]*` Match all accepted chars including a newline without `X`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XJHXTc/1)